# Why does MySQL Workbench automatically create multiple keys when creating relationships between tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database, schema

Check out the image below. In the `movie_custom` table you'll see that when I added a 1:m relationship between `plist_field` and `movie_custom`, MySQL Workbench added keys for the attached tables of `plist_type` and `plist_view_type` in additional to the key I was expecting.

Why is that?

Can/should I remove them?

Or if I should keep them, how do I auto-insert the key values from the deeper tables when doing an insert into `movie_custom` and I know a key of `plist_field`?

[image]

Comment: indexes are required for FKs. older innodb versions didn't create them automatically, so you had to create the indexes manually before linking the tables. newer innodbs do create the index, but regardless-  you end up with indexes on the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If we execute this schema creation:**

```
create table parent
(   pid int auto_increment primary key,
    theirName varchar(100) not null
);

drop table if exists child;
create table child
(   cid int auto_increment primary key,
    theirName varchar(100) not null,
    pid int not null,
    foreign key `fk_c2p` (pid) references parent(pid)
);
```

**Examine what happened to the child:**

```
mysql> show create table child \G;
CREATE TABLE `child` (
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `theirName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`),
  KEY `fk_c2p` (`pid`), -- ******************** AUTO created by mysql
  CONSTRAINT `child_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pid`) REFERENCES `parent` (`pid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

From the manual page [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> ... *index_name* represents a foreign key ID. The *index_name* value is
>   ignored if there is already an explicitly defined index on the child
>   table that can support the foreign key. Otherwise, MySQL implicitly
>   creates a foreign key index that is named according to the following
>   rules:
>
> > If defined, the CONSTRAINT *symbol* value is used. Otherwise, the
> >     FOREIGN KEY *index_name* value is used.
> >
> > If neither a CONSTRAINT *symbol* or FOREIGN KEY *index_name* is defined,
> >     the foreign key index name is generated using the name of the
> >     referencing foreign key column.

So, back to your questions.

A. Why are they created? They are created because mysql creates them as specified above. They facilitate speedy reversal lookups. When a parent row is to be deleted, a fast non-table scan of children is mandated to allow or disallow the parent row removal. The auto-generated key (or one already satisfying it) is used for this purpose.

B. Should you delete them? No. Why not? Read A.

C. How do you "auto-insert the key values from the deeper tables": you acquire the id of the parent (anywhere in the hierarchy) ahead of time such as using [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) or other program logic.